# Does dangerouslySetInnerHTML prevent invalid HTML from being set?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I have a component that is deployed on user's websites where I want the admin to be able to add HTML to their own website, so I am using `dangerouslySetInnerHTML` on a `div`.

I am trying to figure out whether a user might break their website by providing invalid HTML input, but have been unsuccessful so far, so I am wondering if there is any validation already built into this feature?

I have tried adding things like `</html>`, `<script>console.log(</script>`, `</script>`, and so far I have been unsuccessful in breaking the website. I would have expected errors with all of the above.

It seems like all of these breaking changes are removed from the DOM as soon as they are added.

Comment: you want to know if **dangerously**SetInnerHTML is sanitized?

Comment: No, it's not. It's right there in the name - it's dangerous as hell!

Comment: @DerekPollard Maybe sanitized isn't the right word, but I don't know how else to describe the above behavior.

Comment: The docs say it's mostly dangerous because it allows XSS attacks (plus, setting some element's innerHTML to bad HTML syntax in a DOM is harmless, as opposed to the browser having to parse broken HTML code)

Comment: that's just how the DOM works, nothing to do with react. you can't set invalid markup and have it stick, you would have to serve broken markup from the server to get it to "work".

Comment: `</html>, <script>console.log(</script>, </script>` is invalid HTML. invalid != dangerous. dangerouslySetInnerHTML can add *dangerous* HTML that can evaluate arbitrary code on client side (as the name suggests), that's all that needs to be known. I'm not sure if it's a good idea to suggest exact exploits in the answer.

Comment: @estus I'm not worried about exploits, as it's only admins that can edit. I am concerned with admins who don't understand code adding invalid html/js/css and breaking their on site.

Comment: @David You can be sure that dangerouslySetInnerHTML  can evaluate arbitrary JS code on client side. It's dangerous for this reason, not because it can break a layout with invalid markup. In case it's your own app, don't use it for unsafe HTML - or at least process HTML with sanitize lib, preferably with a whitelist of tags/attrs. This way you can also make sure that only valid HTML is provided, if that's your primary concern.